# Hadoop- CDH5 permission

Tags: java, hadoop

I use CDH5 and when I run my project I get the error

> Can not find or edit the main class

I read in some sites that I should edit some files like `Hadoop-env.sh`, but when I edit it and save, I got

[image: this permissions error].

The same error is repeated with other files.

**How I fix this permissions error? or How I can edit files without having permissions?**

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permissions to edit in the `/etc` directory, so use `sudo` to edit.

Open a terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster
```

Comment: Please show your thanks by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).